# Admin Manage Customers - not showing Customer Information

Tags: admin, customer, administration

When I go to Customers/Manage Customers - the list of customers is Displayed.
When I click on a customer or click on "Edit" the page breaks:

```
Customer Information

  Customer View
  Account Information
  Addresses
  Orders
  Billing Agreements
```

See this image: http://postimg.org/image/9nl21664t/full/

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the page that prevents it from rendering.
If you look int he page source you will see that it doesn't end with `</html>`.
If you have error reporting activated then you should see the error in the source.
The last line should be something like this: `Fatal Error: ....`. This should give you an idea of the issue.

If you don't see the error message, edit `index.php` and uncomment this line:

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Remove the '#' sign. and try again.

You might also want to enable the developer mode until you figure out the problem.
Replace in the same `index.php` file this:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

with this:

```
//if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
//}
```

Comment the if statement.

If the error message does not give you an idea on the problem edit the question and add the message.
(this is in the answer section because it's too long to be a comment).

Comment: Good idea, the error appears in the Page source. Thanks!